# Input prompt for C++ program doesn't appear when running in Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I am beginning desktop programming with c++, and when I run the following code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    int main (int argc, char ** argv){
    enum{ max_string = 127};
    static char string[max_string + 1] = "";

    printf("Type in a line\n");
    fgets(string,max_string,stdin);
    printf("the string is %s\n",string);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't see the "Type in a line" prompt when I run the program inside Eclipse.  Instead if I just type in a response, I see what I typed **followed** by:

```
Type in a line
the string is Hello World
```

Why doesn't it first show the prompt "type in a line" before I type in my input?

Comment: What question are you asking?

Comment: What is wrong with the output?

Comment: Why doesn't it first ask for input "type in a line", and then when I type in the string It will echo the string

Comment: The program works fine for me. It prints 'type in a line', waits for input, and then prints 'the string is ..'

Comment: Ya it does fine in cmd but not in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flush the output buffer. I just added `std::cout << std::endl;` and include `<iostream>`. I would suggest you start using `std::cout` instead of `printf`. It's type safe. I tested this inside of Eclipse, without the flush, the line doesn't show up, with the flush it does.

If you **don't** want to move to `<iostream>` I just tested  `fflush(stdout)` from `<stdio.h>` and it works too. However, I strongly encourage the move, stdio.h is the standard for C, the iostream is the standard for C++ and since you're learning C++...